# Faking derived class but calling the real constructor and ignoring base constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following classes:

```
public class Base
{
    private int x;
    public Base(int _x) { x = _x; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    int y;
    public Derived(int _x,int _y) : base(_x) { y = _y; }
}
```

I want to create a fake 'Derived' object, but to call the original constructor and ignore the base constructor.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *fake the Derived class*? what are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't. A derived class *always* needs to call a base class constructor, either explicitly, like in your case, or implicitly if the base class has a default constructor.

Comment: Take a step back and explain to us your real underlying business problem. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I have a base class that I can't change. I want to fake the "Derived" object methods, but call the original implementation of the constructor, and ignoree the call to the base constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I found a solution.
I investigated a little and found out that I can do it with [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fignoringbaseclassconstructor.htm):

```
Isolate.Fake.Instance<Derived(Members.CallOriginal,ConstructorWillBe.Called, BaseConstructorWillBe.Ignored);
```

It allowes me to create a fake object, call the original constructor and ignore the base constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When instantiating a `Derived` object, a constructor of `Base` *must* run; after all, a `Derived` instance is also a `Base`, the logic of creating a `Base` must be executed somewhere in the process.

You might be confusing not calling the `base` constructor with the case where it is implicitly called for you; this happends when `Base` has an accesible default constructor:

```
public class Base
{
    private int x;
    public Base() { } //default constructor
    public Base(int _x) { x = _x; }
}
```

Then this is legal:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    int y;
    public Derived(int _y) { y = _y; } //no explicit base() needed.
}
```

But that's only because the compiler will add the implicit call for you. The real code is:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    int y;
    public Derived(int _y) : base() { y = _y; }
}
```

This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to do?